# Order of completed contests and promotions seems random

Tags: support, sorting, promotions

I was looking at the page of [Completed Contests and Community Promotions](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/) and apparently the order in which past events are shown is random. It is not ordered by date nor in any seemingly alphabetic way.

This is confusing since you get older and newer events preceding each other in no apparent order.

[image: past events]

Comment: Technically it's not random, since it's in the same order for me as for you. It's simply unsorted. Or, more likely, sorted by something that's simply not the date. May have been order-of-entry for all we know. If it's backfilled with older data, date-of-entry is not the same as date-of-event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ordering is not random. The issue is that the UI is generated by pulling data from multiple sources. We have a `Contests` table in one database with the following entries (corresponding to the first 6 entries in the list on the page you reference):

1. AmazonAug2018
2. UiPath2018
3. Bluemix
4. Tizen
5. Braintree
6. AmazonOctDec2018

These are pulled from a query like this:

```sql
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM Contests c
LEFT OUTER JOIN ContestsToTags ctt ON ctt.ContestId = c.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t ON t.Id = ctt.TagId
```

Notice no `ORDER BY`, so you *currently* happen to be getting them in the order of assignment of the identity column of the first table listed, but that could change at any time.

Those results are then concatenated with content hard-coded in a file called `StackPromos.yaml`, which simply has a list of 22 contests. You are getting them in the order they are defined, for example the first three listed are:

```
- Id: 1
  StartDate: 2011-11-08
  EndDate: 2011-11-18
...
  Name: Skyrim vs MW3

- Id: 2
  StartDate: 2011-12-16
  EndDate: 2012-01-06
...
  Name: Hat Dash

- Id: 3
  StartDate: 2012-02-27
  EndDate: 2012-03-16
...
  Name: Android Food Fight
```

And then the last one is:

```
- Id: 22
  StartDate: 2021-12-15
  EndDate: 2022-01-05
  Name: Winter Bash 2021
```

The Winter Bash content was added most recently, so that's why those mostly appear at the very end.

Could this be better? Sure. The underlying issue is different content from different teams from different times make up the set of things we want to show on that site, and consolidating them into one source doesn't likely meet the bar for ROI (especially since it can affect multiple teams, and how apps and sites interact with the different bits of data, and the only benefit would be to make that list chronological).

But for now I'll just stick with answering the question asked. :-)

Comment: And it's a great answer, for now we are thoroughly informed.

Comment: Why not just order by the time when the event started?

Comment: @Shadow Yes, of course. I’m simply explaining how it works today, not defending it as how it _should_ work.